# continueUrl not showing in expired email action page - Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My use case is the following:

In my Firebase app, I authenticate users with the Email/Password sign-in method.

When I sign a user up, an email is sent to them to reset their password.

In the same way, when they forget their password, the same method is invoked, and an email is sent to them to reset their password.

In that email, I use the [`sendPasswordResetEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) method of the Firebase Auth JS SDK. So, in the `actionCodeSettings` object, I pass the `url` parameter, where I provide the `url` of my site. So that when the user resets their password, a "CONTINUE" button will appear, and when they click it, they will be able to go back to my site.

All works like a charm, the users reset their passwords, they click "NEXT", they click "CONTINUE", and they are back to my site.

[image: Click next]

[image: Continue link, using the continueUrl]

BUT, if a user is too slow, and they click on a link that has expired, they are transfered to a page that just says "Your request to reset your password has expired or the link has already been used" and there's no continue link or anything else, despite me providing the `url` in the 
`actionCodeSettings` normally, and me seeing the link in the URL of that page (I mean, I can see in the address bar that the URL ends in `&continueUrl=<my_site_url>`.

[image: The dead-end page]

My question is:

- Is this the correct behaviour? Shouldn't the expired link page show the continue URL as well, since it's also there in the URL!
- If this is the correct behaviour, how could I provide my users with a link back to my page?

Comment: I've been looking into this for months, I've ended up with making my own API with firebase functions to check the code on my website and everything, which is a whole lot easier. The link for the doc is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler and if you'd like I can help you with implementing the code that does all of that on your website, that way you have more control too.

Comment: Thank you, I actually wanted to write a reply here. I submitted a feature request and I talked with Firebase support, and we agreed that the only solution is a custom email handler, indeed, for the moment. So, there's no other "official" way around this. It just seemed strange to me, since the redirection link is still there in the URL, so I would expect to be able to use it with the existing functionality...

Comment: yes I agree, but now that I’ve got my head around the custom email handler I prefer that way, I have more control and it’s on my website, which is more professional in its own way.